# How to connect entities

Tags: c#

I have a win forms reporting app. In that app I have two forms, main and config form. Ma app should generate main crystal report with importing subreports like this...

In config form I choose how much time some subreport report is going to repeat and in which order. That config form gives me a name of the report with whom I should search folder for the full path in my main form. So, for each subreport I have a `ModelSection` entity class which looks like this:

```
public class ModelSections
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public string SectionReportNamePath { get; set; }
}
```

For now I should hardcode `SectionID` and `SectionName` somewhere (I don't know where) and to obtain full path with that value I got from config form.

My other class should be a final parameter which will contain all the information for my GenerateReport name and it should look like this:

```
public class ReportLayoutConfig
{
    public List<ModelSections> ReportLayout { get; set; }
    public int SectionsCount { get; set; }
}
```

So when I pass this ReportLayoutConfig as parameter I should have ReportLayoutConfig class which has inside all the information I need and that is:

For example 3 x model section with all the values and the SectionCount. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your post accordingly?

Comment: Why don't you construct the class and `Add` whatever `ModelSections` objects you need to the `ReportLayout` `List`? Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: @uteist OK, I made changes.

Comment: @slawekwin I have a freedom to do this, but I don't know how.